# how to update cakephp2 auth component password form database

Tags: mysql, authentication, components, cakephp-2.1, password-recovery

I am using cakphp2 with auth component. My requirement is to update the password in mysql database using phpmyadmin tool. Which hashing technique cakephp authcomponent use for password field? How do I update it? I am new to cakephp, please help me with this.

my beforesave function code:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**By default** *Security::hash* **takes the type sha1**.

But you can modify it :

```
 Security::hash($password, ‘sha256′, true);
```

http://api.cakephp.org/class/security#method-Securityhash